# Can I put a call to a function inside my if statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var rtn = getParams(entity)
if (rtn.rc == false) { return; }
parameters = rtn.param;
```

Is there a way that I can put the call to getParams inside of the if statement? Also do I need to put the return; in braces with javascript? I am looking for a way to clean up this code snippet. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, did you try `if( getParams(entity).rc == false )` ?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might as well do it all at once

```
if ( (rtn = getParams(entity)).rc ) {
    parameters = rtn.param;
} else {
    return;
}
```

Comment: `if ( rtn = getParams(entity) )` This does not look good to me.

Comment: You're right, I missed the rc attribute, changed now to be accurate. My point was he might as well assign rtn once and not make multiple calls to getParams

Comment: Shouldn't it be `rtn == getParams...`?

Comment: No, `rtn` will get assigned to `getParams`, then `rtn.rc` will be either true or false. This is basically like saying `rtn.rc == true` but `rtn.rc` is sufficient

Comment: But if you do it like this, it will always be `true`.

Comment: Another eg: var items = { "k1": {"rc":"false"}, "k2":"value2"};

console.log((rtn = items["k1"]).rc)

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're after is this...

```
if(getParams(entity).rc == false)
    return;

 parameters = getParams(entity).params;
```

That is perfectly valid (and legal) Javascript.

assuming that getParams returns an Object which has a property of rc, you're good to go. If not, you're going to fail on an uncaught exception for an undefined field (in this case rc).

Also, keep in mind that unlike some other languages false != null and false != undefined and an empty string "" is neither false nor undefined, so make sure rc is *actually false if you want this test to work.

Comment: Where `parameters = rtn.param;` code line in your code? How to get `param` field value after your `if` statement if `.rc != false` ?

Comment: @AndrewD., not sure what you mean. The if only sees if the rc field is false. If that field is false then the function exits. If it is not false then you move on with the Object you fetched... Honestly I can't believe someone just downvoted this answer. Truly... amazing.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel - Don't worry, you still get 18 reputations.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel I mean that you cannot get `param` field value of object returned from `getParam()` and store it into `parameters`.

Comment: @Derek, I don't care at all about the reputation points, what I care about is the integrity of this forum where most people come to help one another, but some feel it necessary to down vote answers which they simply don't like, rather than downvoting answers that are actually wrong!

Comment: @AndrewD. Why not? What do you know about either of these fields that would prevent such an exchange of values?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel - I don't like downvotes when the answer is acutally correct too.

Comment: Why don't you do `if(!getParams(entity).rc)` instead? (just asking)

Comment: @Derek, that is equally valid, but the OP is a beginner, so, I thought I would leave it more readable. Also, the OP is comparing to false but ! would evaluate to true against both false AND null, even though null == false is false! (go figure!)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel, In Q. third line is: `parameters = rtn.param;`. If @Gemma doing update first and second line code with your code lines, then third line (`parameters = rtn.param;`) generate an error _rtn is not defined_. I temporary remove my downvote. But your code is not applicable for Question. Add third line from Question into your answer and I can revote your answer.

Comment: @AndrewD. I think you need to re-examine the code. I'm not entirely sure what you're saying but if you think there's a way that my code could produce an undefined in the "third" line you are mistaken. If rc is false the code exists. If it's not false then we have to assume that the OP intends for the field param to not be undefined. Obviously it *might be undefined, we have not seen any of the other code, but that's not the intention, and so there's no reason to make that assumption. I think you're overlooking the rc part of this and are (mistakenly) hung up on the rtn part.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel, You lost (missed) `parameters = rtn.param;` from original code. Your answer cannot help because line `parameters = rtn.param;` cannot be added after your code lines. Reread question.

Comment: @AndrewD... I realize that it's more fun to type than to actually read and think, but I strongly urge you to do less of the former and more of the latter.  The line parameters = rtn.param; ABSOLUTELY can go right after the line return;... look... I'll even edit my answer to show you how it can go there.  Before you clamber further into this silly argument... pause and actually LOOK at the code!

Answer (score 1):

> > Also do I need to put the return; in braces with javascript?

Not necessary, but its recommended.

> > I am looking for a way to clean up this code snippet. Replace your 3 lines with this.

```
parameters = getParams(entity).rc ? getParams(entity).param : false;
return parameters;
```

Comment: it is not clear from the OP's question that the point is to return the parameters... only to fail if the rc field is false... beyond that there may be more code, no?

Comment: In your example `rtn` is not defined!

Comment: @kiranvj, Now you have double calling `getParams(entity)`? I think is not a good idea.